# Is it possible to load PDF File From Google Drive using flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I had tried but it doesn't load pdf file. This is My Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  PDFDocument document;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDocument();
  }

  loadDocument() async {
    document = await PDFDocument.fromUrl('https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ei6916qmZ34LZECNf5e0DlvB7EJqxqz8');

    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(  
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('PDF FILE'),
        ),
        body: Center(`enter code here`
            child: _isLoading
                ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                : PDFViewer(document: document)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the id in your link (https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1ei6916qmZ34LZECNf5e0DlvB7EJqxqz8) is a folder id.

To get your link, open the file 
[in a new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgxeU.png) and copy the Url into your code.

If the link doesn't work, try the following link format in which you insert the file Id from the Url you got previously.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/fileId/
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to be autenticated user of Google.

And after successfully login

Use these api to ge the drive data:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
```

and also you need to pass the token over the header with Authorization key:

```
 "Authorization" = "Bearer " + token
```

or simply you can create a public link of your file, than copy url and use it.